# Using Object Initializers in Swift to replace AllocWithZone

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7-beta5

I recently updated my Xcode from Xcode 7 beta 4 to Xcode 7 beta 5 and began to have an error that wasn't present before. That being: "AllocWithZone is unavailable in Swift: use Object Initializers instead."

Here is the code where the error is found:

```
public func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
    let copy = self.dynamicType.allocWithZone(zone) as ChartDataSet
    copy.colors = colors
    copy.label = self.label
    return copy
}
```

What do I substitute in place of ".allocWithZone" so that it utilizes an Object Initializer instead of this Obj C component?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25809379/1187415 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this, and the iOS Charts library works for me:

```
let copy=self.dynamicType.initialize() as! ChartDataEntry
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I was using the iOS Charts Library.

Comment: BTW, there's a swift-2.0 branch, updated to beta 5 :-)

Comment: Thank you daniel.gindi. The graphs look great.