# Right way to implement deep copy for object which contains nested objects in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get deep copy of an class object which contains nested object in swift, Can anyone help ?

Code which I tried

Here is my class:

```
class ZLFilters: NSObject, NSCopying {

var filterChoices   : [ZLFilterChoice]?


required init(_ map: Map){

}

init(filterChoices : [ZLFilterChoice]) {

    self.filterChoices = filterChoices
}

func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {

    let copy = ZLFilters(filterChoices: filterChoices!)
    return copy
  }
}
```

But the problem is filterChoices is itself an object, so again internally it does not do deep copy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808972/how-to-implement-copy-constructor-in-swift-subclass

Comment: Write the code for each property. If you have written anything do share your code we can help you in that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do "Deep Copy" in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754559/how-to-do-deep-copy-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your filter choice also conforms:

```
let copy = ZLFilters(filterChoices: filterChoices!.copyWithZone(zone))
```

Comment: var filterChoices   : [ZLFilterChoice]?,
As filterchoices is an array of ZLFilterChoice, so I can't call copyWithZone(zone) on filterChoices(array) object.