# Instantiate Self outside of init in Swift

Tags: swift, initialization, creation

I want to create a class, so that the it's subclasses after calling a function a, will receive a new object of the type Self. I'm insuring, that the subclasses will have the init() method.

In a way I want to clone the object, but actually it's more than that, since I want to create a clone with modified values of the original, so I don't really want to use swifty copy constructor syntax

Why it doesn't work? Definitely this:

```
func myCustomCopy(modificationCommand: Command) -> Test {
    let newInt = modificationCommand.execute(self.myInt)
    return Test(newInt: newInt)
}
```

is not what I want.

Example:

```
protocol Testable {
    var myInt: Int { get set }
    init(newInt: Int)
}

class Test: Testable {
    var myInt = 10
    required init(newInt: Int) { myInt = newInt }

    func myCustomCopy(modificationCommand: Command) -> Self {
        let newInt = modificationCommand.execute(self.myInt)
        return self.init(newInt: newInt)
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why isn't that what you want?

Comment: 2) Why do you need a function `a()` in the first place?

Comment: 3) The last code snippet is totally fine if you just remove the `a()` function entirely. Every subclass will require to have that initializer, and it'll always return the same type of the subclass

Comment: Because I get a base class instantiation and I want to get the Subclass Object returned. In a way it's a copy constructor, but it's more than that. I know that copy constructors are done in another fashion in Swift

Comment: That's not true. 1) a required initializer returns the same type as the class it's called on, whether it's a base class or a subclass. 2) It has absolutely nothing to do with copy construction. 0.

Comment: You just completely changed the entire meaning of your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25808972/3141234

Comment: Note that you may use the (dynamically typed) metatype returned by `type(of:)` to access an initializer of the concrete type of the metatype. In your case, you could use the metatype of `self` to call an initializer of the concrete type of `self`, e.g. `func myCustomCopy() -> Self { return type(of: self).init() }`.

Comment: @Alexander it's still the same. I want to return Self from my function. And the question is how

Comment: @dfri thank you! It worked. Do you want to write a response, so I can mark the question as closed ?

Comment: Happy to help. Sure, I added a somewhat extended version of my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the (dynamically typed) metatype returned by [`type(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2831805-type) to access an initializer of the concrete type of the metatype. Quoting the [Language Reference - Metatypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)

> Use an initializer expression to construct an instance of a type from
>   that type’s metatype value. For class instances, the initializer
>   that’s called must be marked with the `required` keyword or the entire
>   class marked with the final keyword.

So in your case, you could use the metatype of `self` to call a `required` initializer of the concrete type of `self`, e.g.

```
func myCustomCopy() -> Self {
    return type(of: self).init()
}
```

Note that, as specified in the quote above, since you are working with a non-final class, the initializer must be a `required` one.