# Not identical to 'Self'

Tags: swift, nsobject

I want to create a Convertible-like protocol and extend `NSObject` subclasses to implement it. In particular:

```
protocol DataConvertible {

    class func convertFromData(data:NSData) -> Self?

    func data() -> NSData

}
```

I thought implementing would be as simple as:

```
extension UIImage : DataConvertible {

    class func convertFromData(data:NSData) -> Self? {
        let image : UIImage? = UIImage(data: data)
        return image
    }

    func data() -> NSData {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
    }

}
```

But this fails to compile with error `'UIImage' is not identical to 'Self'`. Am I missing something?

Is there another way to implement a protocol like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Disclaimer:** This is a workaround, not an ideal solution.*

---

Using a `typealias` in the `protocol` instead of `Self` works:

```
protocol DataConvertible {
    typealias Result

    class func convertFromData(data:NSData) -> Result?

    func data() -> NSData

}
```

Then return `UIImage?` instead of `Self?` from the implementation of `convertFromData`:

```
extension UIImage : DataConvertible {

    class func convertFromData(data:NSData) -> UIImage? {
        let image : UIImage? = UIImage(data: data)
        return image
    }

    func data() -> NSData {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
    }

}
```

---

**Update:** While this doesn't strictly enforce that `UIImage.convertFromData(data)` will return a `UIImage?` by itself, it does make it enforceable with additional generics in some situations (as pointed out by @hpique [here](https://speakerdeck.com/hpique/learning-swift-by-developing-haneke?slide=12)).

For instance:

```
class Cache<T: DataConvertible where T.Result == T> { /* ... */ }
```

Then, if you try to define `UIImage.convertFromData` to return an `Int?`:

```
class func convertFromData(data:NSData) -> Int? {
    return 1
}
```

With just the protocol in place, it will compile. However, if you try to create a `Cache<UIImage>`, it will fail because `Int` (`T.Result`) is not equal to `UIImage` (`T`).

Comment: -1 because while this *lets* your protocol implementations return `UIImage` (or their own type, whatever it is), it doesn't *enforce* it. For example, try changing your implementation of `convertFromData()` to return an `Int` instead, and just return `2` instead of `image`. It won't complain - unfortunately, this method isn't better than simply returning `AnyObject` in your protocol definition.

Comment: @CraigOtis Fair enough (and thanks for the explanation of the down vote). I was mainly looking for an alternative method of specifying the protocol. But you're right, you lose all the enforcement with it.

Comment: Yea, I'm pondering a solution myself. Rob Napier has a pretty excellent explanation here of why OP's protocol and implementation can't quite work the way he wants: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25645689/88111

Comment: @CraigOtis I believe your -1 is not warranted. You can enforce the type by using generic requirements, as shown here: https://speakerdeck.com/hpique/learning-swift-by-developing-haneke?slide=12. Yes, it's not perfect but we're talking about a workaround for a Swift bug/limitation.

Comment: @hpique Fair enough, downvote removed. The answer has been improved since I originally came across it.

Comment: @CraigOtis This was a nice example of Stack Overflow collaboration. I love this site. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer "should" be:

```
class func convertFromData(data:NSData) -> Self? {
    return self(data:data)
}
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be bug that crashes the playground repl.  Although it crashes the playground/REPL, it does seem to work in an application.

Although it's of limited utility since the code for the invocation also crashes the compiler:

```
let image = UIImage.convertFromData(data)       <--- works

let converter = UIImage.self as DataConvertible
let image = converter.convertFromData(data)     <--- crashes
```

Since this works just fine, I assume it's a playground bug:

```
class Fred {
    var fred:Int

    required init(value:Int) {
        fred = value
    }
}

extension Fred {
    class func makeOne(value:Int) -> Self {
        return self(value:value)
    }
}
```

I suspect the problem lies in the fact that UIImage is a class cluster and UIImage(data:) isn't really an initializer, but is a class method `[UIImage imageWithData:]`

Comment: Yeah, swift is definitely not ready for primetime yet.  Still way too many ways to crash or otherwise confuse the compiler, not to mention the REPL/Playground.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here might be to define this as an `init()` method. That's really the only way for you, in a protocol, to ensure that your callers are going to get back a fully-initialized type in cases where your subclasses don't override the method, while at the same time giving them the opportunity to do so.

Here's a good explanation of why the "promise" your protocol and implementation make may not hold up in all cases:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25645689/88111

Particularly if you have a subclass of `UIImage`, say `AnimatedImage` that does not override the protocol method, leaving the superclass to return `UIImage` instead, which is *not* `Self`.

**Note: This doesn't work, but it seems like it should. Bug?**

```
protocol DataConvertible {

    init?(usingData:NSData)

    func data() -> NSData

}

extension UIImage : DataConvertible {

    convenience init?(usingData: NSData) {
        self.init(data: usingData)
    }

    func data() -> NSData {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
    }

}
```