# Distinction in Swift between uppercase "Self" and lowercase "self"

Tags: swift, self

While playing in a Swift playground I noticed that `Self`, with capital "S", is available along with the lowercase `self`. Is there any difference between them? If so, what are usages for these two, especially for `Self`?

Comment: There are quite a few nuances regarding the values of `self` and `Self` in protocol extensions – I go into this in quite a bit of detail [in this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42037852/2976878).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`Self` refers to the type of the current "thing" inside of a protocol (whatever is conforming to the protocol). For an example of its use, see [Protocol func returning Self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self).

The official docs I've found for `Self` is in [Protocol Associated Type Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_543) in The Swift Programming Language. It surprisingly is not documented in the sections on protocols or on nested types:

However, now there is a [paragraph about `Self Type`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID610) including a code example in the official Swift Programming Language's [chapter about Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html)

Comment: I'm having a picky, pedantic day. But don't worry! I've taken time out from alienating my friends to say: to completely answer the question technically this answer should explicitly say that `self` is largely what Objective-C people think it is. With discussion of structs, enums, etc, probably being an unnecessary detour.

Comment: See "Protocol Associated Type Declaration" in the language reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html

Comment: Its covered really well in WWDC 2015 Video on Protocol Oriented Programming: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=408  -- go to 16:05 in the video for the exact piece on Self type.

Answer (score 13):

`Self` can also be used in classes, and is useful. [Here](https://medium.com/@cnliusen/swift-use-self-to-let-subclass-return-instances-of-subclass-6c7915833bf3) is an article about it.

Here is an example. You have a class called `MyClass`. `MyClass` have methods returning instances of it. Now you add a subclass of `MyClass` called `MySubclass`. You want these methods to return instances of `MySubclass` instead of `MyClass`. The following code shows how to do it. Note that the methods can be either instance methods or class methods.

```
class MyClass: CustomStringConvertible {

    let text: String

    // Use required to ensure subclasses also have this init method
    required init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }

    class func create() -> Self {
        return self.init(text: "Created")
    }

    func modify() -> Self {
        return type(of: self).init(text: "modifid: " + text)
    }

    var description: String {
        return text
    }

}

class MySubclass: MyClass {
    required init(text: String) {
        super.init(text: "MySubclass " + text)
    }
}

let myClass = MyClass.create()
let myClassModified = myClass.modify()

let mySubclass = MySubclass.create()
let mySubclassModified = mySubclass.modify()

print(myClass)
print(myClassModified)
print(mySubclass)
print(mySubclassModified)
```

The following line printed out:

```
// Created
// modifid: Created
// MySubclass Created
// MySubclass modifid: MySubclass Created
```

Answer (score 9):

in protocol & Extension declaration use Self else self

```
extension protocolName where Self: UIView 
{
  func someFunction()
  {
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
  }
}
```

Comment: IMO, the `where` here is an excellent example of what `Self` is.

Answer (score 7):

I think this question could use a simpler answer, more focussed on the **difference** between `Self` and `self`, and perhaps aimed at people newer to Swift.

#### `self` - explicit reference to the current type or instance of the type in which it occurs.

```swift
class MyClass {
  func showClass() {
       print("\(self)")
    }
  }
let someClass = MyClass()
someClass.showClass()
// prints "MyClass"
```

#### `Self` - *Used specifically in `protocol` and `extension` declarations* to refer to the eventual type that will conform to the protocol.

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
   static func returnSelf() -> Self
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
   // define class
}

MyClass.returnSelf() 
// returns MyClass
```

The difference is that `self` is used in types and instances of types to refer to the type that it's in; and `Self` is used in protocols and extensions where the actual `type` is not yet known.

In even simpler terms, `self` is used within an existing type; `Self` is used to refer to a type that `Self` is not yet in.

Read more here:

- `Self` - https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_543
- `self` - https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html
- Both -
  https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/swift-keywords-v-3-0-1-f59783bf26c

Answer (score 3):

I understand Self as a type name(class name for example) and self as an instance of a class/struct , for example:

```
struct Person {
     static var documentNumner = "9484930"
     var name: String
     var computedFullName: String {
        return ("\(self.name) with document number: \(Self.documentNumner)")

    }
}
```

You can't use self with a static property but you can use Self

Answer (score 3):

**self-*refers to the instance or object of a class.***

```
  class SampleClassOne {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

**Self-*refers to the type of protocol or extension.***

```
    class SampleClassTwo {
    static let name: String = "Hello"
    private func printName() {
        print("\(Self.name)")
    }
}

protocol SampleProtocol {
    func sampleFunc() -> Self
}
```

Another example to simply understanding together.

```
 extension Int {
    var add: Self { //refer to the Type
        return self + 100 //refer to the instance
    }
}
print(5.add)
```

Answer (score 1):

Self can also be used as a return type in the protocol extension method body which will return confirming type instance, and for type casting with "as". Please see example below:

```
extension <Protocol-Name> where Self:<Class-Name> {
static func foo(_ param:Type)-> Self{
    guard let abc = method() as? Self else{
        return xyz
    }
}}
```

In the nutshell, Self can be used to refer the Type which confirms to the protocol.