# swift What difference between 'self' and 'Self'?

Tags: swift

[image]

Question: What difference between 'self' and 'Self'?     How do I use "Self" in  a function implementaion When I define a function in a superclass to return subclass's type?

What type should I return on behalf of function caller's self type？ Is base type NSObject or not？

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: `Self` is only intended to be used for generic constraints. What you likely want to do is using `self.dynamicType`.

Comment: You would return something like `self.dynamicType.init()`. But you can only call initializers marked as `required`.

Answer (score 17):

When you’re writing protocols and protocol extensions, there’s a difference between **Self** (capital S) and **self** (lowercase S). When used with a capital S, **Self** refers to the type that conform to the protocol, e.g. `String` or `Int`. When used with a lowercase S, self refers to the value inside that type, e.g. **“hello Swift”** or **786**.

As an example, consider this extension on `BinaryInteger`:

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    func squared() -> Self {
        return self * self
    }
}
```

Remember, **Self** with a capital S refers to whatever type is conforming to the protocol. In the example above, `Int` conforms to `BinaryInteger`, so when called on `Int` the method effectively reads this:

```
func squared() -> Int {
    return self * self
}
```

On the other hand, **self** with a  *lowercase*  S refers to whatever value the type holds. If the example above were called on an `Int` storing the value 8 it would effectively be this:

```
func squared() -> Int {
    return 8 * 8
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use `self`, not `Self`.

Also, as others have noted, try `self.dynamicType`.

Moreover, I would advise you to google "How to Check Type Swift" on Google.

Hope that helped :)

Quote from this link : [Distinction in Swift between uppercase "Self" and lowercase "self"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863810/swift-difference-between-self-and-self)

"Self refers to the type of the current "thing" inside of a protocol (whatever is conforming to the protocol). For an example of its use, see Protocol func returning Self.

The only official docs I've found for Self is in Protocol Associated Type Declaration in The Swift Programming Language. It surprisingly is not documented in the sections on protocols or on nested types."

Moreover: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5479

Comment: Hey there, see OP's question was what is the difference between the two, not which to use. So please include an actual answer to the question in your post.

Comment: also, advise to google things should be a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: Well, sometimes, that is the only answer you can give when the answer is already readily available on the web...