# How can I invoke a method on `Self` in a Swift extension?

Tags: swift, extension-methods

When I try to evaluate this extension

```
extension Int {
    static var allOnes: Int {return ~Self.allZeros}
}
```

I get

> x.swift:2:38: error: use of unresolved identifier 'Self'
>      static var allOnes: Int {return ~Self.allZeros}

I can use lowercase `self`, though.

But `allZeros` is a type method, so I thought that `Self` should work. It looks silly to invoke a type method on an instance (though of course I know it makese sense). Why am I getting this error? Do I have to manipulate the value of `Self` somehow in my extension to get to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinction in Swift between uppercase "Self" and lowercase "self"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27863810)

Comment: I read that question and all of the answers without finding an answer to my specific question. I know exactly what `Self` refers to I even have *no problem* using `Self` as a method parameter within a protocol. My question is how can I use `Self` _in an expression_ in which I invoke a type method on it. Did I miss that answer in the referenced question?

Comment: As far as I can see, it just boils down to "`Self` doesn't mean what you want it to mean", so the actual meaning of `Self` seems to be a relevant answer.

Comment: Ahhhh the key idea is _will conform to the protocol_ which makes no sense in an _extension_. TBH it's pretty opaque, but clear once pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since allZeros is already a method of Int you can just do it like this:

```
extension Int {
    static var allOnes: Int { return ~allZeros }
}
```

Comment: That's the right Swift idiom of course! Well done. But any idea why `~Self.allZeros` generates that error? It's as if we can use `Self` as a type specifier but not in an expression.

Comment: The 'Self' expression is used inside a protocol (not an extension) and refers to the type that will conform to that protocol.

Comment: _That's_ what I was looking for. Beautiful.

Answer (score 3):

```
extension Int {
    static var allOnes: Int {return ~self.allZeros}
}
```

In a static/class context, `self` refers to the type.

In a non-static context, you could use `self.dynamicType.`.

Also note there is a proposal to allow `Self` to access type in non-static contexts (see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md)

Comment: "In a static/class context, self refers to the type." -- I didn't know that, but it makes perfect sense.