# Why do Self and self sometimes refer to different types in static functions?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-protocols

Recently I have been developing multiple heavily protocol-oriented application frameworks with Swift and noticed a few (seemingly) odd behaviors with static functions in protocol extensions, specifically where the extension functions are invoked from metatypes.

The way I initially discovered these behaviors was in troubleshooting a bug where the type of an object changed in a seemingly impossible way. I traced the problem down and eventually determined that it is because in a static function, `Self` and `self` can potentially hold different types (note: I've taken to calling these "Big S Self" and "Little s self" respectively). I'll demonstrate this with a bare bones example from something I whipped up in a Playground:

```
class SomeBaseClass: SomeProtocol {}

class SomeChildClass: SomeBaseClass {}

protocol SomeProtocol {}

extension SomeProtocol {
    static private func getName() -> String {
        return "\(self): \(type(of: self))"
    }

    static func ambiguousName() -> String {
        return getName()
    }

    static func littleName() -> String {
        return self.getName()
    }

    static func bigName() -> String {
        return Self.getName()
    }
}

let child: SomeBaseClass.Type = SomeChildClass.self // SomeChildClass.Type

print(child.ambiguousName())          // "SomeChildClass: SomeBaseClass.Type\n"
print(child.littleName())             // "SomeChildClass: SomeBaseClass.Type\n"
print(child.bigName())                // "SomeBaseClass: SomeBaseClass.Type\n"

print(SomeChildClass.ambiguousName()) // "SomeChildClass: SomeChildClass.Type\n"
print(SomeChildClass.littleName())    // "SomeChildClass: SomeChildClass.Type\n"
print(SomeChildClass.bigName())       // "SomeChildClass: SomeChildClass.Type\n"

print(SomeBaseClass.ambiguousName())  // "SomeBaseClass: SomeBaseClass.Type\n"
print(SomeBaseClass.littleName())     // "SomeBaseClass: SomeBaseClass.Type\n"
print(SomeBaseClass.bigName())        // "SomeBaseClass: SomeBaseClass.Type\n"
```

It can be seen that when static functions are invoked from a metatype, the result may differ if that metatype is assigned to a variable with a declared type of a parent class's metatype.

My question is how does `Self` know what type it is? How then does `self` know what type it is? It didn't make sense to me why `self` was even accessible in a static function anyway, since there is no instance in the first place. I would have thought that one should use `Self` exclusively, but now I'm thinking this isn't the case since `Self` and `self` have proven to produce different results in some scenarios.

Additionally, is there any reason why `self`'s type is used when either `Self` or `self` is omitted, as in the return statement `return getName()` in the `ambiguousName()` function?

For me, I think the weirdest part is when `type(of: self)` returns `SomeBaseClass.Type` when called from the `child.littleName()` function invocation. Shouldn't the "dynamic type" still be of `SomeChildClass`?

Comment: Self refers to the type of the current "thing" inside of a protocol . For an example of its use, see [Protocol func returning Self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self).

The only official docs I've found for Self is in [Protocol Associated Type Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_543) in The Swift Programming Language. It surprisingly is not documented in the sections on protocols or on nested types.

Comment: You're right. @Thennarasan it surely can be used to return an object of the current "thing". I used this quite frequently, actually. The lack of documentation is what initially drove me to ask the question _"Why?"_ since although I use this frequently, I don't truly understand what is happening on a deep level.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was too imprecise at some points. Note that even `static` functions have a concept of `self`. In Swift methods `self` denotes the object the method has been called on.

Comment: I noticed that, and I respect your decision. Your information was no doubt helpful. Perhaps someone else can provide even more background on how this all works. Thanks for your feedback @Sulthan

Answer (score 17):

#### TL;DR

The value of `Self` in a protocol extension is determined by a complex set of factors. It's almost always preferable to use `self` at static level, or `type(of: self)` at instance level in place of `Self`. This ensures that you're always working with the dynamic type that the method is called on, preventing weird surprises.

---

First of all let's simplify your example down a bit.

```
protocol P {
    init()
}

extension P {
    static func createWithBigSelf() -> Self {
        return Self()
    }
    static func createWithLittleSelf() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
}

class A : P {
    required init() {}
}

class B : A {}


let t: A.Type = B.self

print(t.createWithBigSelf()) // A
print(t.createWithLittleSelf()) // B
```

We can see that using `Self` will return a new instance of `A`, whereas using `self` will return a new instance of `B`.

To understand just why this is the case, we need to understand exactly how Swift calls protocol extension methods.

Looking at the IR, the signature for `createWithBigSelf()` is:

```
define hidden void @static (extension in main):main.P.createWithBigSelf () -> A (
 %swift.opaque* noalias nocapture sret, // opaque pointer to where return should be stored

 %swift.type* %Self, // the metatype to be used as Self.

 i8** %Self.P, // protocol witness table for the metatype.

 %swift.type* // the actual metatype the method is called on (self).
 ) #0 {
```

<sup>(Signature for `createWithLittleSelf()` is almost identical.)</sup>

4 invisible arguments are generated by the compiler – one for a pointer for the return, one for the protocol witness table of the conforming type, and two `swift.type*` arguments to represent `self` and `Self`.

This therefore means that *different* metatypes can be passed to represent `self` or `Self`.

Looking at how this method is called:

```
  // get metatype for B (B.self).
  %3 = call %swift.type* @type metadata accessor for main.B() #4

  // store this to to t, which is of type A.Type.
  store %swift.type* %3, %swift.type** @main.t : main.A.Type, align 8

  // load the metatype from t.
  %4 = load %swift.type*, %swift.type** @main.t : main.A.Type, align 8

  // get A's metatype.
  %5 = call %swift.type* @type metadata accessor for main.A() #4

  // call P.createWithBigSelf() with the following parameters...
  call void @static (extension in main):main.P.createWithBigSelf () -> A(

    %swift.opaque* noalias nocapture sret bitcast (       // the address to store
      %C4main1A** @main.freshA : main.A to %swift.opaque* // the return value (freshA)
    ),

    %swift.type* %5, // The metatype for A – this is to be used for Self.

    i8** getelementptr inbounds ( // The protocol witness table for A conforming to P.
      [1 x i8*], 
      [1 x i8*]* @protocol witness table for main.A : main.P in main, i32 0, i32 0
    ),

    %swift.type* %4 // The metatype stored at t (B.self) – this is to be used for self.
  )
```

We can see that `A`'s metatype is getting passed in for `Self`, and `B`'s metatype (stored in `t`) is getting passed in for `self`. This actually makes quite a lot of sense if you consider that the return type of `createWithBigSelf()` if called on a value of type `A.Type` will be `A`. Thus `Self` is `A.self`, while `self` remains `B.self`.

As a general rule then, the type of `Self` is determined by the static type of the thing that the method is called on. (Therefore in your case when you call `bigName()`, `Self.getName()` is calling `getName()` on `SomeBaseClass.self`).

This also holds for instance methods, for example:

```
// ...

extension P {
    func createWithBigSelf() -> Self {
        return Self()
    }
    func createWithLittleSelf() -> Self {
        return type(of: self).init()
    }
}

// ...

let b: A = B()

print(b.createWithBigSelf()) // A
print(b.createWithLittleSelf()) // B
```

The methods are called with a `Self` of `A.self`, and a `self` that's an instance of `B`.

---

#### Existentials

Things get *much* more complicated when you start working with existentials (see [this great WWDC talk on them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9By9KLs51Dc)). If you're calling the extension methods directly (i.e they *aren't* protocol requirements), then for instance methods, the value of `Self` is determined by the static type of the value when you box it in the existential container, for example:

```
let b: A = B()
let p: P = b // metatype of b stored as A.self.

print(p.createWithBigSelf()) // A()
print(p.createWithLittleSelf()) // B()
```

```
let b = B()
let p: P = b // metatype of b stored as B.self.

print(p.createWithBigSelf()) // B()
print(p.createWithLittleSelf()) // B()
```

What happens is that the existential container also stores the metatype of the value (along with the value buffer and protocol and value witness tables), which is taken from its static type at the time of boxing. This metatype is then used for `Self`, leading to the somewhat surprising behaviour demonstrated above.

With metatype existentials (e.g `P.Type`), the existential container just stores the metatype along with the protocol witness table. This metatype is then used for *both* `Self` and `self` in a call to a static method in a `P` extension, when that method isn't a protocol requirement.

Methods that *are* implementations of protocol requirements will be dispatched to dynamically via the protocol witness table for the type conforming to that protocol. In this case, the value of `Self` is replaced by the type that *directly* conforms to the protocol (although I'm not entirely sure why the compiler does this).

For example:

```
protocol P {
    static func testBigSelf()
}

extension P {
    static func testBigSelf() {
        print(Self.self)
    }
}

class A : P {}
class B : A {}

let t: P.Type = A.self // box in existential P.Type
t.testBigSelf() // A

let t1: P.Type = B.self
t1.testBigSelf() // A
```

In both cases, the call to `testBigSelf()` is dispatched dynamically via `A`'s protocol witness table for conformance to `P` (`B` [doesn't get its own protocol witness table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42286148/2976878) for `P` conformance). Therefore `Self` is `A.self`. It's exactly the same story with instance methods.

This most commonly comes up in generic functions, which dispatch protocol requirements dynamically via the protocol witness table*. For example:

```
func foo<T : P>(t: T) {
    t.testBigSelf() // dispatch dynamically via A's PWT for conformance to P.
}

foo(t: A()) // A
foo(t: B()) // A
```

It doesn't matter whether an instance of `A` or `B` is passed in – `testBigSelf()` is dispatched via `A`'s PWT for conformance to `P`, therefore `Self` is `A.self`.

(* Although the compiler can optimise by generating specialised versions of generic functions, this doesn't change the observed behaviour.)

---

#### Conclusion

For the most part, the type of `Self` is determined by the *static type* of whatever the method is called on. The value of `self` is simply the value *itself* that the method is called on (a metatype for a static method, an instance for an instance method), passed in as an implicit parameter.

The full breakdown of what we discovered is that the values of `self`, `Self` & `type(of: self)` in protocol extensions are:

- Static scope (`static` methods / computed properties)

  - `self`: The metatype value which the method is called on (therefore must be dynamic). Existential metatypes don't make a difference.
  - `Self`: The metatype value for the *static* type of the metatype that the method is called on (i.e when called on a given `T.Type` where `T : P`, `Self` is `T.self`). When the method is called on an *existential* metatype `P.Type`, and isn't a protocol requirement, `Self` is equivalent to `self` (i.e is dynamic). When the method *is* a protocol requirement, `Self` is equivalent to the metatype value of the type that *directly* conforms to `P`.
  - `type(of: self)`: The dynamic metatype of the metatype `self`. Not that useful.
- Instance scope (non-`static` methods / computed properties)

  - `self`: The instance that the method is called on. No surprises here.
  - `Self`: The metatype value for the *static* type of the instance that the method is called on (i.e when called on a given `T` where `T : P`, `Self` is `T.self`). When called on an *existential* `P`, when the method isn't a protocol requirement, this is the static type of the instance *when it was boxed*. When the method *is* a protocol requirement, `Self` is equivalent to the metatype value of the type that *directly* conforms to `P`.
  - `type(of: self)`: The *dynamic* metatype value for the instance that the method is called on. Existentials don't make a difference.

Due to the sheer complexity of factors that determine what the value of `Self` is, in most cases I would recommend using `self` and `type(of: self)` instead. That way there's far less chance of being bitten.

---

#### Answering your additional questions

> Additionally, is there any reason why `self`'s type is used when either `Self` or `self` is omitted, as in the return statement `return getName()` in the `ambiguousName()` function?

That's just the way it is – `getName()` is merely syntactic sugar for `self.getName()`. It would be inconsistent with instance methods if were syntactic sugar for `Self.getName()`, as in instance methods `Self` is a metatype, whereas `self` is the actual *instance* – and it's much more common to be accessing other instance members, rather than type members from a given instance method.

> For me, I think the weirdest part is when `type(of: self)` returns `SomeBaseClass.Type` when called from the `child.littleName()` function invocation. Shouldn't the "dynamic type" still be of `SomeChildClass`?

Yeah, that puzzles me too. I would expect the dynamic type of `child` to be `SomeChildClass.Type` rather than `SomeBaseClass.Type`. In fact, I'd even go so far as it say it might be a bug (feel free to file a report at [bugs.swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org) to see what the Swift team make of it). Although in any case, the metatype of a metatype is pretty useless, so it's actual value is fairly inconsequential.

Comment: Great information on what you found digging in the IR. This is the kind of stuff I was looking for. I did actually file a bug in Jira for the Swift team to look at. I'll see if they come up with any kind of response. Hopefully there is a concrete answer out there. If/when I find out, I will post a comment here so that you can append it to your already very informative answer. Thanks again for all the effort you put into this response!

Comment: Our issue SR-3862 is getting some attention :)

Comment: For anyone who's wondering what is `A.Type` in the line of `let t: A.Type = B.self`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438368/swift-whats-the-difference-between-metatype-type-and-self). `A.Type` is similar to `AnyClass`. It could have also be written with `let t: AnyClass = B.self` Though it would then be able to take the type of _any_ class. Using `A.Type` would *enforce* it to be a subclass of type `A`

Comment: Jeez ! That was dope !