# Why do I have to add != to make Equatable works?

Tags: swift

Why do I have to add != to make the comparison correct?

```
import UIKit

class Person: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

extension Person {
    static func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.age == rhs.age
    }
    static func !=(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return !(lhs == rhs)
    }
}

let first = Person(name: "John", age: 26) 
let second = Person(name: "John", age: 26)

/**
 * return false (which is correct) when we implement != function. But,
 * it will return true if we don't implement the != function.
 */
first != second
```

**Update:**
So I got why I had to add `!=` function to make it work. it's because the class inherit the `NSObject` which uses `isEqual` method behind the scene.  But why does adding `!=` function make it work? Any explanation here?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Alexander Sorry the class code is to complex to be put in here. But the answer might be simple, because I read it's just a new requirement for new version of Swift that you have to implement `!=` to make it work.

Comment: Well that assumption is just false. A default `!=` implementation is provided which calls `!(a == b)`. I'm not exactly sure what kind of answer you're looking for, if you don't even give us a way to recreate the issue

Comment: Sure give me time, I'll find a way to make the class simpler and see if I can reproduce it using the simpler class, and then put it here. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: While I haven't an answer, I appreciate the updated question. You have my upvote.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony Now that's a better question. This is odd. I suspect it has something to do with how `Equatable` interacts with `NSObject`

Comment: Compare point #2 of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42286148/2976878. In short, subclasses cannot directly reimplement a superclass' protocol conformance. While your implementation of `==` can be *statically* dispatched to, it cannot be *dynamically* dispatched to (such as from within the standard library's `!=` operator implementation that invokes `==` and negates the result). As others have already said, you want to override `isEqual` (*and* `hash`!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this is not a direct answer to your question.

As Alexander commented, Swift Standard Library has this default implementation of `!=`:

[Equatable.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Equatable.swift)

```
  @_transparent
  public static func != (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    return !(lhs == rhs)
  }
```

I cannot explain this behavior well, but the `==` operator in the default implementation above is solved to the default `==` operator for `NSObject`, as `NSObject` (and also its descendants) is already `Equatable` and has an `==` operator to conform to `Equatable`. So, even if the explicit representation is exactly the same as your `!=` definition, the `==` operators are solved to different implementations.

---

A general guidline to define your own equality to an `NSObject`-descendant class:

**Make `==` and `isEqual(_:)` consistent**

You may store your class's instance inside `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` (in many cases implicitly). Inside their methods, `isEqual(_:)` is used when equality check is needed, not the `==` operator.

So, just defining the `==` operator without giving a consistent override to `isEqual(_:)`, such methods will generate unexpected result.

To make consistent `==` and `isEqual(_:)`,

**just override only `isEqual(_:)` and do not define `==` and `!=` explicitly**.

The default implementation of `==` for `NSObject` (and also `!=`) uses `isEqual(_:)`.

```
class Person: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let other = object as? Person {
            return self.name == other.name && self.age == other.age
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

(See **ONE MORE THING** at the bottom.)

---

**ADDITION**

Similar behavior can be found on non-`NSObject` classes.

```
class BaseClass {
    var a: Int

    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a
    }
}
extension BaseClass: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: BaseClass, rhs: BaseClass) -> Bool {
        print("`==` of BaseClass")
        return lhs.a == rhs.a
    }
}
let b1 = BaseClass(a: 0)
let b2 = BaseClass(a: 0)
print(b1 != b2) //->`==` of BaseClass, false ### as expected

class DerivedClass: BaseClass {
    var b: Int

    init(a: Int, b: Int) {
        self.b = b
        super.init(a: a)
    }
}
extension DerivedClass {
    static func == (lhs: DerivedClass, rhs: DerivedClass) -> Bool {
        print("`==` of DerivedClass")
        return lhs.a == rhs.a && lhs.b == rhs.b
    }
}
let d1 = DerivedClass(a: 0, b: 1)
let d2 = DerivedClass(a: 0, b: 2)
print(d1 != d2) //->`==` of BaseClass, false ### `==` of DerivedClass and true expected
```

Seems we need extra care when overriding `==` for already `Equatable` classes.

---

**ONE MORE THING**

(Thanks for Hamish.)

You know you need to implement `==` and `hashValue` consistently when creating a type conforming to `Hashable`. `NSObject` is declared as `Hashable`, and its `hashValue` needs to be consistent with `hash`. So, when you override `isEqual(_:)` in your `NSObject`-descendent, you also should override `hash` consistent with your overridden `isEqual(_:)`.

So, your `Person` class should be something like this:

```
class Person: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let other = object as? Person {
            return self.name == other.name && self.age == other.age
        }
        return false
    }

    override var hash: Int {
        //### This is just an example, but not too bad in practical use cases.
        return name.hashValue ^ age.hashValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it seems there is no other way than overriding `isEqual`. Because if I use `==` for swift class and `isEqual` for `NSObject`, it's only a matter of time before I forget that it's an NSObject, write `==`, and breaking everything. By overriding `isEqual` I think it can make the code more consistent, so we can just use `==` everywhere. And btw, where do you find the implementation of `!=` method?

Comment: @EdwardAnthony, sorry I'v forgotten to include the link for it. Updated soon.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Note if you're overriding `isEqual`, you should really also override `hash` to ensure that if two objects are determined equal, they have the same hash value. And the behaviour you're seeing is due to subclasses not being to directly reimplement a superclass' conformance to a protocol (compare point #2 of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42286148/2976878 :) )

Comment: @Hamish, I should have mentioned it! (Frankly, i've been almost forgotten it when I wrote my answer.) Thank you so much!.

Answer (score 4):

`NSObject` conforms to `Equatable` but uses its own `isEqual` method and in terms of `isEqual` both instances are not equal. `NSObject` calls `==` only if your form of `!=` is implemented, which contains `==`.

If you delete `NSObject` (and add `Equatable`) the implementation of `==` works as expected.

The recommended way for `NSObject` is to override `isEqual` with a custom implementation and omit `==` (and `!=`).

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is wrong. You should not implement `==` or `!=`. An NSObject subclass automatically implements `==` as `isEqual:`. You are disrupting that. You should implement `isEqual:` and that's all.