# Swift | Set with NSObject

Tags: swift3, set, hashable, equatable

I'm trying to create a Set with custom objects.
This is working, If I use a Set of my custom objects there is no duplicates :

```
public class AttributesGroup: Hashable, Equatable, Comparable {

    open var id: Int!
    open var name: String!
    open var position: Int!

    public init (id: Int = 0, name: String = "", position: Int = 0) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
    }

    open var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return id.hashValue
        }
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: AttributesGroup, rhs: AttributesGroup) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    public static func < (lhs: AttributesGroup, rhs:AttributesGroup) -> Bool {
        return lhs.position < rhs.position
    }
}
```

I extend my class with NSObject, since NSObject already implements Hashable protocol (and also Equatable) I have to override hashValue, and this is not working anymore, If I use a Set of my custom objects there is duplicates, what do I do wrong here ? :

```
public class AttributesGroup: NSObject, Comparable {

    open var id: Int!
    open var name: String!
    open var position: Int!

    public init (id: Int = 0, name: String = "", position: Int = 0) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
    }

    open override var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return id.hashValue
        }
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: AttributesGroup, rhs: AttributesGroup) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    public static func < (lhs: AttributesGroup, rhs:AttributesGroup) -> Bool {
        return lhs.position < rhs.position
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: As always, **never ever** declare properties as implicit unwrapped optionals which are initialized in an `init` method with non-optional values. Unfortunately many *horrible* tutorials suggest this *horrible* habit. Don't do that, never. Remove the exclamation marks.

Comment: Compare point #2 of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42286148/2976878 as well as https://stackoverflow.com/q/33319959/2976878

Comment: @vadian You're totally right, this is a bad habit. Thanks.

Comment: @Hamish Very interesting, I get it now thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSObject is a Cocoa type. The rules for NSObject are different from the rules for Swift. To make an NSObject work in a set, it must have an implementation of `isEqual` consonant with its implementation of `hash`.

Comment: Indeed this is working with implementation of isEqual and hash. Thanks