# Swift - How to get class that extended from protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols

Is there a way that I could get the Class type or Struct type that extended my Protocol?

Here are my sample code:

```
protocol a {}

extension a {
    static func list(completion: ([StructType] -> Void)) {
        var items = [StructType]()
        ...
        completion(items)
    }
}

struct b{}
extension b: a {}

struct c{}
extension c: a{}
```

In this case I want to dynamically get the type of struct **a** and **b**, so that I could generate a list of it and return.

Thank you in advance for kindly answering my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Self` keyword

```
protocol P {
    init()
}

extension P {
    static func list(completion: ([Self]) -> Void) {
        let items = [Self(), Self(), Self()]
        print(Self.self)
        completion(items)
    }
}

struct B {}
extension B: P {}

class C {
    required init() {}
}
extension C: P {}

B.list{ print($0) }
C.list{ print($0) }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply.

Comment: You sir save me.

Comment: `type(of: self)` might be better. It gets the dynamic type of the object, so if you have class `D` that inherits from `C` it will give you the answer `D` (`Self` will still be `C`).

Comment: @JeremyP You mean `self` (given that it's at static level) – that would give you the dynamic value of the metatype that the method is called on. Although I agree it's worth noting the difference between `self` and `Self` in this context, as the results can be quite surprising in some cases as [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42037852/2976878) shows.

Comment: @Hamish `Self` is the static type. `Self.self` gives you the meta object for the static type. So it will always give you a `C`. That might be what you want, particularly if you are using it to instantiate objects.

Comment: @JeremyP Yes, I know. I don't believe I said otherwise? Although it's not quite "always give you a `C`" – for `D.list{...}`, `Self` will be `D`. It's just the case of `let c : C.Type = D.self; c.list{...}` where `self` vs. `Self` makes the difference for static methods.

Comment: @Hamish I take back what I said, you are correct in this case.

Comment: I'm not really sure but in this case static is better for because I need to instantiate that *B* and  *C*

Comment: @Norak I was just keeping it as close to your example as possible