# How do you get a subclass' version of a computed variable in a generic function with Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

I am trying to define a identifier (class name) static computed variable on a UITableViewCell extension and access the identifier by sending a subclass to a generic function.

When accessing the Subclass.identifier, I get the name of the subclass, but when accessing it from a generic function, it returns UITableViewCell

code:

```
protocol Identifiable {
    static var identifier: String { get }
}

extension Identifiable {
    static var identifier: String { return String(describing: Self.self) }
}

extension UITableViewCell: Identifiable { }

class Subclass: UITableViewCell {

}

print("\(Subclass.identifier)") // Output: "Subclass"

func blah<T: Identifiable>(_ cellType: T.Type) {
    print("\(cellType.identifier)")
}
blah(Subclass.self) // Output: "UITableViewCell"
```

How can I get the Subclass identifier in the generic function without having to conform to the Identifiable protocol on all of my UITableView subclasses?

Comment: Related: [Why do Self and self sometimes refer to different types in static functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037852/why-do-self-and-self-sometimes-refer-to-different-types-in-static-functions). The behaviour you're seeing is the "existential when the method is a protocol requirement" behaviour. Due to the sheer complexity of factors that determine the value of `Self`, `self` is nearly always preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unnecessary `Self`.  You want:

```
extension Identifiable {
    static var identifier: String { return String(describing: self) }
}
```

When you say `Self.self` you are saying "This class's self" and "This class" is the the thing that you have extended (being UITableViewCell).  When you just say `self` you are saying "this thing" where "this thing" is the thing that is executing the function, so `Subclass`