# Self.self strange behavior in protocol extension

Tags: swift

In this sample code, `Self.self` doesn't behave as expected. Depending on the type of the parameter chosen, the identifier property has not the same value.

```
protocol Identifiable : class {
    static var identifier: String { get }
}

extension Identifiable {
    static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }
}

class Animal : Identifiable {}
class Tiger : Animal {}

Animal.identifier // Animal
Tiger.identifier // Tiger

func identifiableIdentifier<T: Identifiable>(of type: T.Type) -> String {
    type // Tiger.Type
    return type.identifier
}

identifiableIdentifier(of: Tiger.self) // Animal 


func animalIdentifier<T: Animal>(for type: T.Type) -> String {
    type // Tiger.Type
    return type.identifier
}

animalIdentifier(for: Tiger.self) // Tiger
```

Does someone know why ?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42037852/2976878. `Self` is a weird and (not so) wonderful type in a protocol extension; you're better off just using `self` in your case.

Comment: Thanks @Hamish, it is hard to find the right words on Google