# Swift doesn't call overridden class var in protocol extension function with associated type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

This is the code I tried to minimize as much as possible:

```
protocol LengthValidater {
    static var minLength: Int { get }
}

protocol Validater: LengthValidater {
    associatedtype ValidateType

    static func generateValue() -> ValidateType
}

extension Validater {
    static func generate() {
        print(Self.minLength) // prints correctly
        generateValue()
    }
}

protocol TextValidateable: Validater where ValidateType == String {}

extension TextValidateable {

    static func generateValue() -> String {
        print(Self.minLength)
        return ""
    }

}

class TextValidater: TextValidateable {
    class var minLength: Int {
        fatalError()
    }
}

class UserIdentifier: TextValidater {
    override class var minLength: Int {
        return 10
    }
}
```

Calling `UserIdentifier.generate()` will crash the app, while it clearly should not since it should use dynamic dispatching and call the overridden `class var`. **When I remove the associated type and/or return type of `generateValue()`, it does not crash.**

Why does it crash?

Comment: You want to use `self` instead of `Self` (so just do `print(minLength)`). Using `Self` as a value in a protocol extension [is a path to madness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42037852/2976878).

Comment: @Hamish O jeez I sure have lots to learn about protocols :)