# Covariant 'Self' type cannot be referenced from a stored property initializer

Tags: swift, swift5

In the below code, I don't understand why I get the said error when using `Self()` ? The code just works fine if I replace it with `Fireman()` .

```
final class Fireman {

    var numOfServices = 0

    private init(){}
    static var shared = Self() <-------- Here !!!

    func extinguishFire() {
        self.numOfServices += 1
        print("Spraying water...\(self.numOfServices)")
    }
}
```

Also the reason I had to mark the class `final` is because, without that the error message was that I had to include a `required` initializer (and when I do that I again get an error because my initializer is `private`). So just to avoid further subclassing , though against my will I declared the class final

Comment: I have even tried replacing static with class - didn't workout

Comment: And why do you need to use Self when you have a working solution?

Comment: If I change my class name later I don't want go around updating everywhere. that's why. More importantly I wanna understand `Self` more deeply as an inherent keyword in Swift

Comment: Xcode has a Refactor command that will help you with that. A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self)

Comment: Have you read this answer?  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42045937/793607

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is pretty similar to [Protocol func returning Self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self), but enough different that it's probably worth answering separately. There are two issues here.

The first issue is why you need `final`. As in the above question, the problem issue is that you're making a promise the compiler can't prove you'll keep.

Consider the following subclass:

```
class LocalFireman: Fireman {
    let zipcode: String
    init(zipcode: String) { self.zipcode = zipcode }
}
```

What should `LocalFireman.shared` return? It can't return a Fireman. You said it had to return Self (i.e. LocalFireman). And it can't return a `LocalFireman`, since it doesn't have a zipcode to init with. So now what?

Swift doesn't let you get into this corner by requiring you to either nail down the specific type of `shared` (i.e. it will always be `Fireman`, even if you call it on a subclass), or you need to promise there will be no subclasses, or you need to require all subclasses to implement `init`:

```
required init() {}
```

OK, but you got that far. You marked it `final`, and it still complains. Now you're hitting a compiler limitation. The whole point of `Self` is covariance; [it's the dynamic type at the point of calling, not the static type in context](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-adding-a-self-type-name-shortcut-for-static-member-access/2056). It's not just a handy way to say "my type" and this was an choice (though it's something that could change I think). It means "my covariant type" even if you're in a situation where there can't be any subtypes.

All that said, given the `private` init, I'm confused why you say marking it `final` is "against my will." If all `init` are private, this can't be subclassed anyway, so it seems you want a final class, and if so, then just put the class name where it goes. `Self` is not for that problem (today).

This leaves open the question as to why you can't do this with a required init. `Self` as a "type of class" and `Self` as "type of thing conforming to a protocol" are treated as the same thing. So you can't think about this only in the class situation; anything can "inherit" (conform to) a protocol. So `Self` can potentially refer to a struct. Structs can be any size. So allowing a stored property to be of type `Self` creates memory layout problems. (I don't think Swift promises that classes will always be implemented as a pointer, either, so this could cause the same problem for classes, at least in principle.)

You can return a value of type `Self` from a function, but you can't put one in a stored property (this is true both of static and non-static properties), and Swift also doesn't allow them for computed properties (I assume this is just for consistency). So the following is allowed (and in fact useful):

```
class Fireman {
    required init() {}
    static func make() -> Self { return Self() }
}
```

And this is what `Self` is for.