# Swift method returning array of Self

Tags: swift, types

Why can't I write a function which returns an array of type Self, whereas I can do it for a single Self item?

I can write :

```
class func test(text: String) -> [Any] {
      return [
        Self.init(text: text),
        Self.init(text: text),
        Self.init(text: text)
      ]
}
```

But the compiler doesn't know the output types.

And `[Self]` does not work..

I need that for subclass reasons..

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643745/covariant-self-type-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-stored-property-initializer for a detailed answer around this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Covariant 'Self' type cannot be referenced from a stored property initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643745/covariant-self-type-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-stored-property-initializer)

Comment: No because -> Self works actually, I have the issue only for returning an array of Self. I can use generic function, but I still need to infer the type using "as ..." when I'm using it..