# Implementing NSCopying in Swift with subclasses

Tags: swift, introspection

Consider two classes. The first is `Vehicle`, an `NSObject` subclass that conforms to `NSCopying`:

```
class Vehicle : NSObject, NSCopying {

    var wheels = 4

    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        let vehicle = self.dynamicType()
        vehicle.wheels = self.wheels
        return vehicle
    }
}
```

The second class, `Starship`, inherits from `Vehicle`:

```
class Starship : Vehicle {

    var photonTorpedos = 6
    var antiGravity = true

    override func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        let starship = super.copyWithZone(zone) as Starship

        starship.photonTorpedos = self.photonTorpedos
        starship.antiGravity = self.antiGravity
        return starship
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile because:

> Constructing an object of class type 'Vehicle' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer.

So I go ahead and add a required initializer:

```
required override init () {
    super.init()
}
```

And now the app compiles, and `Starship` objects respond to `copy()` properly.

Two questions:

1. Why does constructing an object with a metatype need a `required` initializer? (It appears the initializer I wrote does nothing.)
2. Is there anything I wrote incorrectly, or *should* add to the initializer? Is there a case I'm not considering?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### **The Short Answer**

You cannot use `self.dynamicType()` without marking `init()` as `required` because there's no guarantee subclasses of `Vehicle` will also implement `init()`.

### **Exploring The Problem**

Taking a look at *[The Swift Programming Language: Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)*, it's mentioned how

> subclasses do not inherit their superclass initializers by default

The situations in which a subclass **will** inherit its superclass' initialisers are:

> Assuming that you provide default values for any new properties you
>   introduce in a subclass, the following two rules apply:
>
> **Rule 1**
>
> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it
>   automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> **Rule 2**
>
> If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass
>   designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by
>   providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it
>   automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initialisers.

Take a look at the example:

```
class MySuperclass {
    let num = 0

    // MySuperclass is given `init()` as its default initialiser
    // because I gave `num` a default value.
}

class MySubclass : MySuperclass {
    let otherNum: Int

    init(otherNum: Int) {
        self.otherNum = otherNum
    }
}
```

According to the information above, since `MySubclass` defined the property `otherNum` without an initial value, it doesn't automatically inherit `init()` from `MySuperclass`.

Now suppose I want to add the following method to `MySuperclass`:

```
func myMethod() {
    println(self.dynamicType().num)
}
```

You'll get the error you described because there is no guarantee subclasses of `MySuperclass` will implement `init()` (and in this example they don't).

To solve this problem you therefore need to mark `init()` as `required`, to ensure all subclasses of `MySuperclass` implement `init()`, and so calling `self.dynamicType()` is a valid thing to do. It's the same problem as in your question: Swift knows `Vehicle` implements `init()`, however it doesn't know any subclasses will implement `init()` and so you need to make it `required`.

An alternative solution, which isn't suitable in your example, is to mark `Vehicle` as `final`, meaning `Vehicle` can't be subclassed. Then you'll be able to use `self.dynamicType()`; but you might as well just use `Vehicle()` in that case.

Comment: Great answer, particularly on using `NSCopying`. For more discussion on copying in Swift (without `NSCopying`) you may also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup. Agree: great answer.

Comment: Great answer! This should be in **The Swift Programming Language**

Answer (score 0):

You need a `required` initializer because subclass implementation of a required initializer in Swift needs it.

Per Swift Documentation on [Required nitializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html):

> You must also write the required modifier before every subclass
>   implementation of a required initializer, to indicate that the
>   initializer requirement applies to further subclasses in the chain.

Comment: Actually, it seems to work fine, even if I delete `super.init()`.

Comment: Yes, because you override it. I should have said it basically needs an initialiser as it will not necessarily inherit it from it's super class maybe..

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me… aren't *all* methods inherited from the super class? Can you say more about this? Is there any documentation you can cite?