# How do I refer to the class type to call constructor or other class functions inside the same class?

Tags: ios, swift

I've got this code I need to copy & paste to many classes (I know...) and I am trying to find a way not to edit the class name for each new class. I would also prefer if I can refactor the code without thinking too much about renaming class func and calls to initializers. Is there a way?

```
@objc class MyClass : NSObject, NSCopying {
    init() {}

    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
       return MyClass()
    }

   class func myFunction() {}

   func myMethod() {
       MyClass.myFunction()
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The classes are `NSObject` subclasses so using generics won't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having your class' superclass as `NSObject`, you could make their superclass `MyClass`, which you would define like so:

```
@objc class MyClass : NSObject, NSCopying {
    required override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        return self.dynamicType()
    }

    class func myFunction() {
        // ...
    }

    func myMethod() {
        self.dynamicType.myFunction()
    }
}
```

`dynamicType` refers to the instance's class. For an instance of `MyClass` the `dynamicType` is `MyClass`. For a subclass of `MyClass`, `dynamicType` would refer to that subclass.

For an explanation on `required` initialisers and `dynamicType` have a look at [Implementing NSCopying in Swift with subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144475/implementing-nscopying-in-swift-with-subclasses/30337998#30337998)