# Swift throw run time error when using generic class

Tags: swift, generics, design-patterns

Seems swift has some problems when it deal with generic class. Seems these code can be compiled but will have run time error when meet `println(act.actId)`. It throw out a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` bug.

Is there any other way or workaround about this issue?

```
public class Item {
    public var id: String
    public init(str: String) {
        id = str
    }
}

public class Account: Item {
    public var actId: String
    public override init(str: String) {
        actId = "antId: \(str)"
        super.init(str: str)
    }
}

public class Keyword: Item {
    public var keywordId: String
    public override init(str: String) {
        keywordId = "keywordId: \(str)"
        super.init(str: str)
    }

}

public class Creator<T: Item> {
    public func parse(str: String) -> T {
        var result: T = T(str: str)
        return result
    }
}

var a = Creator<Account>()
var act = a.parse("Apple")
println(act.actId)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this doesn't compile in playground.

> Subclasses do not inherit their superclass initializers by default -> [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

You need marking `init()` as `required`

I've changed it and it works now

```
public class Item {
    public var id: String
    public required init(str: String) {
        id = str
    }
}

public class Account: Item {
    public var actId: String
    public required init(str: String) {
        actId = "antId: \(str)"
        super.init(str: str)
    }
}

public class Keyword: Item {
    public var keywordId: String
    public required init(str: String) {
        keywordId = "keywordId: \(str)"
        super.init(str: str)
    }

}

public class Creator<T: Item> {
    public func parse(str: String) -> T {
        let result: T = T(str: str)
        return result
    }
}

var a = Creator<Account>()
var act = a.parse("Apple")
print(act.actId)
```

See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144475/implementing-nscopying-in-swift-with-subclasses) for more details