# How to make a method in superclass create subclass objects?

Tags: swift, inheritance

```
class Car {
     func upgrade() -> Car { 
        return Car()
     }
}


class RacingCar : Car {

}

let racingCar = RacingCar()
let upgradedRacingCar = racingCar.upgrade()
// ideally upgradedRacingCar should be a RacingCar
```

How to make the upgrade method create RacingCar objects if its called on a subclass, **without** implementing it in the RacingCar?

Comment: Related: [Protocol func returning Self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this. If it's a class method:

```
class Car {
    class func upgrade() -> Self { 
        return self()
    }
}
```

If it's an instance method:

```
class Car {
    func upgrade() -> Self { 
        return self.dynamicType()
    }
}
```

The return type `Self` means "the class of me, polymorphically". So we return a Car if this is Car and a RacingCar if this is RacingCar. The notation `self()` and `self.dynamicType()` are shorthand for calling `init`; these are both classes, so that's legal. I presume you will have a more elaborate initializer. You will have to make your initializer `required` to calm the fears of the compiler (as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30087117/341994)); thus, neither of the above will compile unless `init()` is marked `required` in Car.

Comment: And see my book, which covers this exact situation: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_type_reference