# How to extend Array functionality for arrays of a specific type?

Tags: arrays, swift, class, swift2

(Using my usual playing card example)
I am trying to make a generic `CardCollection` that both a `Deck` and a `Hand` would inherit from.  Both Decks and Hands would need to be sorted or shuffled, but there would be some differences such as initialisation and whether the method for removing a `Card` for use elsewhere is `Deal` (for a `Deck`), `Play`, or `Discard` (for `Hand`s).

```
class CardCollection: <Some protocol or another that Arrays use> {
    var collective = [Card]()
    // CardCollection-specific functions

    // pass-through functions
    func append(newCard: Card) {
        collective.append(newCard)
    }
}


class Deck: CardCollection {
    // deck-specific functions
}
class Hand: CardCollection {
    // hand-specific functions
}
```

The way I'm currently implementing it (see above) is with a Class that contains an Array of Cards, but I can't use my classes like they were Arrays without writing tons of pass-through functions to get my classes to conform to all the protocols as an Array.

What I need is a way that lets me do things like `for card in deck` (as if `deck` were simply an `Array<Card>`) without writing tons and tons of wrapper functions just to get the `CardCollection` to conform to all the necessary protocols.

How do I make a CardCollection that functions like it's just an `Array<Card>` without making pass-through functions on every function used by the protocols that `Array` uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a `CardCollection` protocol which inherits from
`RangeReplaceableCollectionType`,
and a protocol extension with default implementations to forward all 
access methods to the underlying `collective` array:

```
struct Card { 
    // Simplified for demonstration purposes:
    let rank : Int
    let suit : Int
}

protocol CardCollection : RangeReplaceableCollectionType {
    var collective : [Card] { get set }
}

extension CardCollection  {

    var startIndex : Int { return collective.startIndex }
    var endIndex : Int { return collective.endIndex }

    subscript(position : Int) -> Card {
        get {
            return collective[position]

        }
        set(newElement) {
            collective[position] = newElement
        }
    }

    mutating func replaceRange<C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == Card>(subRange: Range<Int>, with newElements: C) {
        collective.replaceRange(subRange, with: newElements)
    }
}
```

Then

```
struct Deck: CardCollection {
    var collective = [Card]()

}

struct Hand: CardCollection {
    var collective = [Card]()

}
```

both conform to `RangeReplaceableCollectionType` and can be treated
like an array:

```
var deck = Deck()
deck.append(Card(rank: 1, suit: 1))
deck[0] = Card(rank: 2, suit: 3)

for card in deck {
    print(card)
}

var hand = Hand()
hand.append(deck.first!)
```

If `Deck`/`Hand` are *classes* instead of structs then they
need to be `final` or have a `required init()` method,
compare
[Why use required Initializers in Swift classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085264/why-use-required-initializers-in-swift-classes).

---

Slightly more general, you can define an `ElementCollection` 
protocol (independently of the `Card` type)
which behaves like an array (by conforming to
`RangeReplaceableCollectionType`) and forwards the access to 
an underlying `elements` array:

```
protocol ElementCollection : RangeReplaceableCollectionType {
    typealias Element
    var elements : [Element] { get set }
}

extension ElementCollection  {

    var startIndex : Int { return elements.startIndex }
    var endIndex : Int { return elements.endIndex }

    subscript(position : Int) -> Element {
        get {
            return elements[position]

        }
        set(newElement) {
            elements[position] = newElement
        }
    }

    mutating func replaceRange<C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == Element>(subRange: Range<Int>, with newElements: C) {
        elements.replaceRange(subRange, with: newElements)
    }
}
```

Which is then used as

```
struct Card { 
    // Simplified for demonstration purposes:
    let rank : Int
    let suit : Int
}

struct Deck: ElementCollection {
    var elements = [Card]()

}

struct Hand: ElementCollection {
    var elements = [Card]()

}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: I still need to provide forwards for _all_ the methods listed [on the documentation page for `Range ReplacableCollectionType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_RangeReplaceableCollectionType_Protocol/index.html) in my protocol extension, right?

Comment: @cjm: No, only those which don't have a default implementation. The above example only implements forwards for startIndex, endIndex, subscript (from the Indexable protocol) and replaceRange. The default implementation for the other methods like first, append or generate (used in for .. in) then use these methods.

Comment: Then I must've missed something that doesn't have a default implementation in there (most likely the protocol extension) somewhere, since it's complaining that `Type 'Deck' does not conform to protocol 'RangeReplaceableCollectionType'`.

NEVERMIND (RE the above): I was being silly and forgot to expand the issues in the Issue Navigator for details