# How to fix my custom UITextField object in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, object, swift3, uitextfield

I have issues when I'm trying to create a custom object (UITextField) in Swift 3, it didn't happen before.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is working fine the problem is somewhere else. You should use the default init with frame instead of the required one, or create your convenience init with desired properties.

```
class ThemeTextFieldCollab : UITextField {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder ?? "", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.gray])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }
}
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code but I have an issue : "Value of type 'ThemeTextFieldCollab' has no member 'attributedPlaceholder'"

At the line "self.attributedPlaceholder..."

Comment: UITextView does not have `attributedPlaceholder` or `placeholder`.

Comment: ThemeTextFieldCollab is a TextField and not a TextView so I think your code is wrong

Comment: Ok, now I have the error: "Type 'NSAttributedString.Key' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'foregroundColor'"

Comment: That is because of your Swift version, replace `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor` with `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`. I updated the answer code as well.

Comment: I checked your source code again and it is working good as an `UITextField`, well, hope my answer was useful somehow since you shouldn't be using the required init. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085264/why-use-required-initializers-in-swift-classes

Comment: Try with that super implementation. Both are working fine in my Xcode.

Comment: I updated my post with a screenshot, It doesn't work, I don't know why :/

Comment: if you just remove the required init, what does it show? Usually the quick fix provides a default required init implementation.

Comment: I did what you said and I have exactly the same required init, with the error :/

Comment: have you tried removing that SwiftTheme or any external library?

Comment: or even cleaning the build folder.

Comment: Keep in mind that your code is working fine. The problem is probably somewhere else. Try running this individually or fix the other problems in your code that you mentioned. Make sure everything that was opened is closed (, {, [, ...

Comment: Yes it works because I test my code source on the friend's mac and it works. I don't know why there is error when it's on my mac.