# Generic settings class in Swift 2

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2

I'm trying to implement a class in Swift 2 for a single setting of any type that uses `NSUserDefaults` under the covers.

**Problem:** How do I define a class for storing and retrieving any type of object, including `Dictionary`?

I have a solution that works with `AnyObject` which consists of a generic protocol (`Settable`) and a generic class (`Setting`).  `SettingsStore` is a wrapper around `NSUserDefaults`.

```
// MARK: Settable Protocol

public protocol Settable {
    typealias T
    init(key: String, defaultValue: T, settingsStore: SettingsStore)
    var value: T { get set }
    func loadCurrentValue()
}

// MARK: Settings Class

public class Setting<T: AnyObject>: Settable {
    private let key: String
    private let defaultValue: T
    private let settingsStore: SettingsStore

    private var currentValue: T?

    public required init(key: String, defaultValue: T, settingsStore: SettingsStore) {
        self.key           = key
        self.defaultValue  = defaultValue
        self.settingsStore = settingsStore
    }

    public var value: T {
        get {
            if self.currentValue == nil {
                self.loadCurrentValue()
            }
            return self.currentValue!
        }
        set {
            self.currentValue = newValue
            self.settingsStore.setObject(newValue.toAnyObject(), forKey: self.key)
        }
    }

    public func loadCurrentValue() {
        let optionalValue: T? = self.settingsStore.objectForKey(key) as? T
        if let value = optionalValue {
            self.currentValue = value
        } else {
            self.currentValue = self.defaultValue
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to create a setting like this:

```
let specialId: Setting<String>
init() {
    self.specialId = Setting<String>(
        key: "specialId",
        defaultValue: "<somevalue>",
        settingsStore: self.settingsStore)
}
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't work with value types, such as `String`, `Bool`, `Int`, `Double`, `Array`, or `Dictionary` because they are all value types and value types don't conform to the `AnyObject` protocol.

I've solved the problem for some of these using a protocol and extensions based on `NSString` and `NSNumber`, but a solution `Dictionary` is proving to be elusive (I don't need a solution for `Array` at the moment so I haven't spent time trying to solve that one).

```
// Change definition of Setting class like this:
public class Setting<T: AnyObjectRepresentable>: Settable {
    ...
}

public protocol AnyObjectRepresentable {
    func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject
    static func fromAnyObject(value: AnyObject) -> Self?
}

extension AnyObjectRepresentable where Self: AnyObject {
    public func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
        return self
    }
    public static func fromAnyObject(value: AnyObject) -> AnyObject? {
        return value
    }
}
extension String: AnyObjectRepresentable {
    public func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
        return NSString(string: self)
    }
    public static func fromAnyObject(value: AnyObject) -> String? {
        let convertedValue = value as? String
        return convertedValue
    }
}
extension Bool: AnyObjectRepresentable {
    public func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
        return NSNumber(bool: self)
    }
    public static func fromAnyObject(value: AnyObject) -> Bool? {
        let convertedValue = value as? Bool
        return convertedValue
    }
}
// Add extensions for Int and Double that look like the above extension for Bool.
```

I tried two different approaches for `Dictionary`.  The first one is similar to the `String` approach:

```
extension Dictionary: AnyObjectRepresentable {
    public func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
        let value = self as NSDictionary
        return value
    }
    public static func fromAnyObject(value: AnyObject) -> Dictionary? {
        let convertedValue = value as? Dictionary
        return convertedValue
    }
}
```

Xcode gives me the following error on the first line of the `toAnyObject()` method implementation:

*'Dictionary' is not convertible to 'NSDictionary'*

Next I tried extending `NSDictionary` directly:

```
extension NSDictionary: AnyObjectRepresentable {
    public func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
        return NSDictionary(dictionary: self)
    }
    public static func fromAnyObject(value: AnyObject) -> NSDictionary? {
        let convertedValue = value as? NSDictionary
        return convertedValue
    }
}
```

Xcode gives me the following error on the declaration of `fromAnyObject()`:

*Method 'fromAnyObject' in non-final class 'NSDictionary' must return `Self` to conform to protocol 'AnyObjectRepresentable'*

I'm at my wits.  Is this solvable?

Thanks,
***David***

**UPDATED 2015-09-15 16:30**

For background, here is the definition and an implementation of `SettingsStore`:

```
public protocol SettingsStore {
    func objectForKey(key: String) -> AnyObject?
    func setObject(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String)
    func dictionaryForKey(key: String) -> [String:AnyObject]?
}
public class UserDefaultsSettingsStore {
    private let userDefaults: NSUserDefaults
    public init() {
        self.userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    }
    public init(suiteName: String) {
        self.userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: suiteName)!
    }
}
extension UserDefaultsSettingsStore: SettingsStore {
    public func objectForKey(key: String) -> AnyObject? {
        return self.userDefaults.objectForKey(key)
    }
    public func setObject(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String) {
        self.userDefaults.setObject(value, forKey: key)
        self.userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
    public func dictionaryForKey(key: String) -> [String : AnyObject]? {
        return self.userDefaults.dictionaryForKey(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using AnyObject, what about using Any?

Comment: Regarding your error, have a look at [Protocol fun returning Self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self).

Comment: I had looked at that earlier - Rob Napier has a really good write-up on the subject, but unfortunately it didn't help me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute **AnyObject** with **Any**, I think you'll get the results you're looking for. Specifically, replace this line:

```
public class Setting<T: AnyObject>: Settable {
```

with this line

```
public class Setting<T: Any>: Settable {
```

Comment: I tried that but then I ran into a problem with SettingsStore, which is used to read and write the setting from/to NSUserDefaults.  Any ideas?