# How to return `[Self]` from a Swift Protocol?

Tags: swift, self, swift-protocols

I am having a Protocol implementation as follows.

```
protocol DatabaseInjectable {

    static func deriveObjectFromDBRow(row: [String]) -> Self? // Method - 1

    static func collectAllObjectsForDatabaseAction(action: (Database) -> Void) -> [Self]? // Method - 2
}
```

Where I am successful with the correspondent implementation of `Method - 1` like this:

```
static func deriveObjectFromDBRow(row: [String]) -> Self? {

    ...
}
```

But I could not implement the `Method - 2` like this:

```
static func collectAllObjectsForDatabaseAction(action: (WWDatabase) -> Void) -> [Self]? {

    ...
}
```

There I am getting an error like this:

```
'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class;
```

Any help to return the **array form of** `Self` (the class it self) would be nice.

Comment: Despite having answered several *similar* questions myself (none of which I think answer your *specific* question) I still find the treatment of `Self`unintuitive. Maybe someone can write a definitive guide to this...

Answer (score 1):

If you can set your class `final` you can replace `Self` by the class name

```
final class SampleClass: DatabaseInjectable {
    init() {
    }
    static func deriveObjectFromDBRow(row: [String]) -> SampleClass? {
        return SampleClass()
    }

    static func collectAllObjectsForDatabaseAction(action: (Database) -> Void) -> [SampleClass]? {
        let array = [SampleClass]()
        return array
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be a solution but I need to subclass it. Therefore I can't set it as a ˚Final˚ class.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very well written answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self), but in short, you can define your protocol as such:

```
protocol DatabaseInjectable {

    static func deriveObjectFromDBRow(row: [String]) -> DatabaseInjectable? // Method - 1

    static func collectAllObjectsForDatabaseAction(action: (Database) -> Void) -> [DatabaseInjectable]? // Method - 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the specific class type as a return type. Same as `instancetype` in Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a `typealias` in your protocol `DatabaseInjectable`, and use this as an alias to `Self` type in the classes conforming to your protocol.

```
class Database {
    var desc : String = "Default"
}

protocol DatabaseInjectable {
    typealias MySelf

    static func deriveObjectFromDBRow(row: [String]) -> MySelf?

    static func collectAllObjectsForDatabaseAction(action: (Database) -> Void) -> [MySelf]?
}

class MyClass : DatabaseInjectable {
    typealias MySelf = MyClass

    static func deriveObjectFromDBRow(row: [String]) -> MySelf? {
        return MyClass()
    }

    static func collectAllObjectsForDatabaseAction(action: (Database) -> Void) -> [MySelf]? {
        return [MyClass(), MyClass()]
    }
}

/* example */
let closure : (Database) -> () = { print($0.desc) }
var arr : [MyClass]? = MyClass.collectAllObjectsForDatabaseAction(closure)
/* [MyClass, MyClass] */
```

One drawback here is, however, that you could set e.g. `typealias MySelf = Int` (in the class) and have your functions return an integer/array of integers (rather than self/[Self]), and still conform to you protocol. Possibly this is a deal-breaker.