# Clone a Class without link the 2 instances

Tags: swift

I want to copy/clone an instance of a class in SWIFT but making two are both not related ( referenced)

What is the simplest / correct method for do it ?

please, if something can put a little example, I'd be very grateful :-)

thanks

Comment: Classes are reference type. If you want value type, use structs.

Comment: Explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class

Comment: See also [Protocol func returning Self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self).