# Swift Using Self in Generics & Protocol (w/o Init at method Level)

Tags: swift, generics

**Update:**
The question voted to close this as duplicate deals with `self.init()` which can be solved by marking class final or requiring init. But How does that work on Repositories or return from any other method other than `init`  (My Implementation is @NSManaged Object)

Here is what I want to do. Get a JSON Via Request, then parse it into an object.

```
var req = Request("http://somewhere/story/get/1")
var story = req.parseJsonResponse() as Story
```

The `Request` class somehow looks like this:

```
class Request {

    public var httpJsonResponse : String

    init(_ url : String) {
        //This comes from HTTP
        httpJsonResponse = "{}"
    }

    public func parseJsonResponse<T : IParse>() -> T {

        return T.parse(json: httpJsonResponse)

    }

}
```

Now, I want to make sure that `IParse` implementation has parse method:

```
protocol IParse {
    static func parse(json : String) -> Self
}
```

So far so good, here's the problem with implementation:

```
class Story : IParse {
    required init() 
    {
    }
    public static func parse(json: String) -> Self
    {
        //return self.init() works thanks to @tomahh
        return StoryRepo.ById(1)
    }

}

class StoryRepo {
    public static func ById(_ id : Int) -> Story {
        return Story()
    }
}
```

This does not work. Neither of these work:

1. Returning Story
2. Casting `Story() as! Self`

See updated playground [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/14520669f05504f56f39fbc6ed60ac70).

Comment: Does not work on my playground too.Whether I don't understand it or it's a bug. `cannot convert return expression of type 'Story' to return type 'Self'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protocol func returning Self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self)

Comment: Either make `Story` `final`, or implement a `required` initialiser, and call that on `self` in the static method.

Comment: @Hamish In case we are returning the value?

Comment: @tika I'm not sure I understand you. Marking the class as `final` allows you to achieve this without adding a `required` initialiser.

Comment: @Hamish it does not  build for `return StoryRepo.ById(1)` but builds for `return self.init()` in the `parse` method

Comment: @tika Replace `-> Self` with `-> Story`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Story : IParse {
    required init() 
    {
    }

    public static func parse(json: String) -> Self
    {
        return self.init()
    }
}
```

This will work. This makes sure that you actually build an instance of `Self`, so that a `Tale` subclass of `Story` would not create a boring `Story`, but a wonderful tale indeed.

The `required` keyword forces subclasses to override this init, so that we are sure it is valid to actually call `self.init()` within parse.

---

Another solution, if you don't want to struggle with inheritance, would have been to make the `Story` class `final`

```
final Story: IParse {
  public static func parse(json: String) -> Story {
    return Story()
  }
}
```

In this example, because `Story` will never be inherited from, it is safe to call `Story()` and return a `Story` type from the `parse` function.

Comment: Doesn't work.  Can you try on your playground. `use of unresolved identifier 'Self' return Self()`

Comment: Oops, I updated my answer with valid code. Sorry for the misleading first contribution. I'm updating again with more explanation right now!

Comment: See the updated section. How can it implement with result from other methods?