# How is init() relevant in Swift protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols

Protocols in Swift can declare the `init()` method in their definition. However, I can't think of any use case where this solves any problem other than forcing the conforming classes to define the `init()` as in the protocol. We can call the declared methods on the protocol type but init on protocol cannot be used to instantiate its object, which is its only purpose.

What problem does declaring `init()` method in a protocol solve?

Comment: How else would a protocol extension be able to create a new instance of a given type that conforms to the protocol? ;)

Comment: Ah! Right. Good point. Its relevant in protocol extensions.

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self.

Answer (score 3):

I think the real utility comes when it's used as a constraint in a generic class o function. This is real code from one of my projects.

I declare a protocol with a `init`:

```
protocol JSONCreatable {
    init(fromJson json: JSON)
}
```

Then, in a **generic** function where I return a class that conforms to that protocol:

```
import SwiftyJSON

extension JSON {
    func asObject<T>() -> T? where T: JSONCreatable {
        if isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        return T(fromJson: self)
    }

    func asArray<T>() -> [T] where T: JSONCreatable {
        return array?.map{ json in T(fromJson: json) } ?? []
    }
}
```

This allows me to do things like this:

```
let user: User = json["user"].asObject()
let results: [Element] = json["elements"].asArray()
```

Comment: Usually, I find that the generic functions of the form `<T : SomeProtocol>() -> T` are often better written as initialisers in an extension of `SomeProtocol`. In the case of `[T]`, I would also consider writing an `init` in a constrained `Array` extension. Probably just a matter a preference though. I find `let array = [SomeJSONCreatable](json: someJSON)` more natural than `let array: [SomeJSONCreatable] = someJSON.asArray()`.

Answer (score 2):

It forces class to have `init(data: data)` from some data, example:

```
protocol JSONable {
    init(data: JSON)
}
```

forces all classes, that are `JSONable` to have an initialiser from `JSON`, so you are always sure, that you can create an instance from `JSON`.

Comment: Looks like thats what the question says, I think the question is what purpose does it serve (besides ensuring the conformance to implement the init method), if i cannot call Something like `JSONable(data: <*someJson*>)`

Comment: @uchiha well, then I don't get the question, ensuring that you will 100% create an instance is crucial and I can't imagine any other purposes.

Comment: @uchiha, but you can do `func f<T: JSONable>(jsonString: String) -> T { return T(data: parseJSON(jsonString)) }`

Answer (score 2):

It's commonly used in order to allow for protocol extensions and generic placeholders constrained to protocols to call the initialiser on the given *concrete* type that conforms to the protocol. For example, consider [`RangeReplaceableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/rangereplaceablecollection)'s default implementation of [`init<S : Sequence>(_ elements: S)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/RangeReplaceableCollection.swift.gyb#L549):

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {

    // ...

    /// Creates a new instance of a collection containing the elements of a
    /// sequence.
    ///
    /// - Parameter elements: The sequence of elements for the new collection.
    public init<S : Sequence>(_ elements: S) where S.Iterator.Element == Iterator.Element {
      self.init()
      append(contentsOf: elements)
    }
    // ...
}
```

Without `init()` being defined as a protocol requirement of `RangeReplaceableCollection`, there's no way for the extension to know that we can call `init()` in order to create a new instance of the conforming type.

But it can also be used *directly* outside of generics and extensions – for example, it can be used to construct a new instance represented by a given existential metatype (the metatype of 'some concrete type that conforms to a protocol'):

```
protocol P {
    init()
}
struct S : P {
    init() {}
}

let s: P = S()
let s1 = type(of: s).init() // creates a new instance of S, statically typed as P.
```

In this example:

- `type(of: s)` returns the dynamic type of `s` as `P.Type` (an existential metatype), as `s` is statically typed as `P`. Remember that `type(of:)` is a `(T) -> T.Type` operation.
- `init()` constructs a new instance of the *underlying* concrete type, in this case `S`.
- The new instance is statically typed as `P` (i.e boxed in an existential container).

Comment: I think `type(of: s)` will return `S.Type` here. Moreover, we cannot call initializer on `P.Type`

Comment: @Shubham No, because `s` is typed as `P`. And you can call the initialiser on `P.Type` – feel free to try it for yourself :) It's only `P.Protocol` (the type of the protocol itself) that you *can't* call an initialiser on, as it doesn't represent a concrete type.

Comment: I tried it on playground. `type(of: s)` returns `S.Type`, & `P.Type.init()` fails with "P.Type has no member named init"

Comment: @Shubham Try using the code in my example... You've likely typed `s` as `S` – and `P.Type.init()` is not legal. You need to call `init()` on a metatype *value*, typed as `P.Type` (e.g the result of `type(of:)` when applied to some `P` expression).

Comment: Oh, okay. And I double checked it. The dynamic type of `s` changes to `S.type` after assigning it to object of type `S`.

Comment: @Shubham Yes it will do, because the compiler now knows it's an `S`, so doesn't need to bother with existentials :) (but calling `init` on an `S.Type` is obviously just as valid as calling it on a `P.Type`)