# Can I use set placeholder type based on return value?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

I would like to specify a function in a protocol who's return value matches the type of the current implementation class.

```
protocol MakesSelf {
    static func getInstance<T>() -> T
}
```

Except where T is constrained to be the same type of whoever implements MakesSelf, for example

```
class MyThing: MakesSelf {

    class func getInstance<T>() -> T {
        return MyThing()
    }

}
```

It *was* my understanding that the compiler would assign T the type of MyThing based on the return value, but I am instead getting a type conversion error: `Cannot convert return expression of type 'MyThing' to return type 'T'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protocol func returning Self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self).

Comment: The end goal was to return self, but here I just want to know what the compiler constrained `T` to. In my mind, even if the compiler doesn't infer `T = MyThing.Type`, `T` should be equivalent to `AnyObject`, which `MyThing()` conforms to.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a protocol with associated type where your `getInstance()` function will return that type. In the extension of the protocol create a default implementation of that function. Full example:

```
protocol Initializable {
    init()
}

protocol MakesSelf: Initializable {
    associatedtype Object: Initializable = Self
    static func getInstance() -> Object
}

extension MakesSelf {
    static func getInstance() -> Object {
        return Object()
    }
}

class MyThing: MakesSelf {
    required init() {}

    func printSelf() {
        print(MyThing.self)
        print(Object.self)
        // Both will print "MyThing" because Object is a typealias of MyThing class
    }
}
```

Then get your instance:

```
let instance = MyThing.getInstance()
print("\(instance.self)")
/* Will print: MyTestApp.MyThing */
```

As you can see, because you already gave a default implementation of `getInstance()` in the extension of the protocol that is not necessary in the conforming class. In the context of your question, the associated type serves as the "placeholder".

Comment: That's a beautiful bit of code, but actually getInstance was supposed to be returning an object not a Type. My question is why Why T != MyThing.Type in the implementation.

Comment: @OlivierButler it is returning an instance (object). It prints "MyTestApp.MyThing" because I add `.self` in the print statement.

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to confirm I understand correctly; the Self in the definition of MakesSelf is referring to the protocol. That means, when we call MyThing.getInstance(), anything which conforms to MakesSelf would do, however you provide an implementation which refers to Object directly. That means we have to call Object(), and can't return MyThing() or some other spurious value. When we see what function Object() refers to in any specific case, we get the current implantation's initialiser. What confuses me is why MyThing() is returning anything, given the initialiser is is empty.

Comment: Protocols would be useless if there were no classes, structs, etc which would implement them, that's why I see `Self` as the future `self` of the object conforming to the protocol. Apple documentation confirms that: " Self refers to the eventual type that conforms to the protocol". About your last statement - it's perfectly fine to have an empty initializer, you do however need to set it as `required` as per `Initializable` requirement.

Comment: And protocol's `associated` type `Object` becomes a `typealias` in the conforming object. So `MyClass.self` and `Object.self` represent the same type within the scope of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was facing was that `T` can't be inferred in the case of `MyThing`. The compiler isn't super helpful when it comes to error messages (at one point I was told `Cannot convert return expression of type 'T' (aka 'MyImplementation') to return type 'T'`)

The solution is to provide some way for the compiler to know what `T` should be (if you wanted it unconstrained, use `AnyObject`, not `T`).

In my case I wanted to return a value of type Self (the implementation's type). This complicates things more than your normal POP problems, since you can't refer to Self in a class/static function.

To get around this, I use Swift's `associatedtype` which allows us to setup a named placeholder for use across an protocol. Since we're defining this at the protocol level, and providing a value, we can setup a named reference to the implementors own type.

```
associatedtype MyType = Self.Type
```

**Note** that `associatedtype MyType = Self` would not work, since self in this context *is the protocol*, not the final implementation's type (which we don't know yet, and we/the compiler won't know until some object actually implements the protocol).

Since we provide a value, when we do implement our protocol the type is already constrained! Since the constraint only refers to the type of the implementation, implementing the protocol is enough to define the type (cool). The best part is that now I can eliminate referring to Self in my `class func` definition:

```
protocol MakesSelf {

    associatedtype MyType = Self.Type

    static func getInstance() -> MyType

}

class MyImplementation: MakesSelf {

    class func getInstance() -> MyImplementation {
        print("Hello")
        return MyImplementation()
    }

}

let myThing = MyImplementation.getInstance()
```

To be super clear here - the class MyImplementation has a typealias called MyType as specified by the protocol. When I compile, the alias will refer to the current implementation. Now when I implement the function getInstance, MyImplementation conforms to MyType.

**Note** that I have to write my function signature in the form of `class func getInstance() -> MyImplementation` and not `class func getInstance() -> MyType`. This is because I am returning the result of a function call `MyImplementation()`, which so happens to conform to MyType's constraint. This is not the same as saying that MyImplementation can by implicitly converted to MyType.

For a good read about trying to make [protocol function specification for returning self see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self), but I wanted to post the specific solution and explanation.