# How to replace self on its implementation

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, type-alias, associated-types

I have this protocol

```
protocol BinaryTreeProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    var info: T { get set }
    var left: Self? {get set}
    var right: Self? {get set}
    func addItem(item: T)
}
```

And I can't complete its implementation.

```
struct BinaryTreeImplementation: BinaryTreeProtocol {
    typealias T = Int
    var info: Int

    var left: BinaryTreeImplementation?  // There is an error here.
    var right: BinaryTreeImplementation? // how can I sort it?

    func addItem(item: Int) {

    }
}
```

Comment: well you can not have a property that contains itself

Comment: @LeoDabus Even if it is optional?

Comment: it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Use a class instead of a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing has two elements:

- the recursive reference to the same type as hinted by the compiler. Basically, you are using a `struct`,whose size should be known at compile time; adding a recursive reference to its type prevents this
- you are using 'Self' in the protocol declaration, which may lead to cases where non-fully initialised instances are created (see: [Protocol func returning Self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self)); i.e you need to use `final` for implementation to make sure the `Self` instances are of specific class and thus fully initialised;

I've modified your code reflecting my comments:

```
protocol BinaryTreeProtocol {
   associatedtype T
   var info: T { get set }
   var left: Self? {get set}
   var right: Self? {get set}
   func addItem(item: T)
}


final class BinaryTreeImplementation: BinaryTreeProtocol {
   typealias T = Int
   var info: Int = 0

   var left: BinaryTreeImplementation?
   var right: BinaryTreeImplementation?

   func addItem(item: Int) {

   }
}
```

Hope this helps and enjoy Swift :)