# Method ... in non-final class ... cannot be implemented in a protocol extension because it returns 'Self' and has associated type requirements

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

This is my code:

```
protocol Person {
    associatedtype Homework

    static func generate(homeWork: Homework) -> Self
}

extension Person {
    static func generate(homeWork: Homework) -> Self {
        fatalError()
    }
}

// Method 'generate(homeWork:)' in non-final class 'Teacher' 
// cannot be implemented in a protocol extension because it 
// returns 'Self' and has associated type requirements
class Teacher: Person {
    typealias Homework = Int
}
```

Despite the strange naming of types, I am curious why it isn't possible to conform a non-final class to a protocol which has a method that returns `Self` and having a `associatedtype` as parameter type.

Note: I am not asking how to fix this problem (because I can just mark my `class` `final`). I want to know why this isn't possible.

I think it is strange. Protocols with `associatedtypes` and `Self` is always a struggle ofcourse, but when using one of two (returning `Self`/`associatedtype` protocol type in parameter) compiles the code just fine.

**Why can't I conform to a protocol which has a default implementation of a method whereas the method has a return type of `Self` and `associatedtype` in a parameter, but when only using one of them the code compiles? Why is both a problem when dealing with inherence (because marking the `class` as `final` fixes the error message, so it has to be something with inherence)?**

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but throwing a fatal error in a default implementation for a required protocol method is a really bad idea, since instead of getting a compile-time error if not implementing that method, you end up getting a runtime exception. Why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I want to do it to demonstrate the compile time error with as less lines/noise as possible

Comment: The problem that you actually describe though and the code you've shown are completely different. You don't conform to the protocol in an extension, but you provide a default implementation for the protocol method returning `Self` and then simply conform to the protocol in the class declaration and try to use the default implementation. So which one is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Since if it was the one you __describe__, that compiles perfectly fine without marking `Teacher` `final`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Ok, I agree the question text was misleading and confusing, I edited it to be more clear. Long story short: why does it give me a compile time error when using BOTH a return type of Self AND using an associatedtype as parametertype, but it compiles fine when using one of the two when dealing with a non-final class?

Comment: Another way to fix is with another `associatedtype` as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38884909/259521

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its because of a compiler limitation. Here's some relevant discussion from people on the Swift team:
https://twitter.com/_danielhall/status/737782965116141568

The original tweet shows what would happen if we tried to create a subclass from `Teacher`, the compiler would not be able to identify it as conforming to the `Person` protocol.

Specifically relevant from the swift team in that thread: "we don't support subtyping when matching protocol requirements. I consider it a missing feature in the language"

So knowing the compiler can't recognize subclasses as conforming to the protocol in these situations they decide to force a final class.