# Why using Self as return type is not considered as the protocol's constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

This is a valid protocol declaration in Swift:

```
protocol Proto1: class {
    func method1() -> Self
    func method2() -> [Proto1]
}
```

But this isn't:

```
protocol Proto2: class {
    func method1(param: Self)
    func method2() -> [Proto2]
}
```

The error message is:

> Protocol 'Proto2' can only be used as a generic constraint because it
> has Self or associated type requirements

So it seems that, when using `Self` as function's return type, Swift doesn't consider that as a constraint of the protocol being defined and hence it's OK to use the protocol itself as functions' return type. But when using `Self` as function's parameter type, the behavior is completely different.

I wonder why such a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's not useful to have a `Self` as a parameter type of a method. Suppose that you *can* do:

```
protocol P {
    func f(_ x: Self)
}

class A: P {
    func f(_ x: Self) {
        // not relevant
    }
}

class B: A { }
```

Now suppose I have:

```
func g(x: A) {
    // what can I do with x?
}
```

The fact is, there is no way to call `x.f`. Because I can pass an instance of `B` to `x`, in which case `x.f` would accept a `B` instead. `x` could be an instance of any subclass of `A` that I have no way of knowing at compile time, so I don't know what I can pass to `x.f`.

---

Compare that to `Self` used as the return type:

```
protocol P {
    func f() -> Self
}

// Implementation:
class A: P {
    func f() -> Self {
        self
    }
}

class B: A { }

func g(x: A) {
    let foo: A = x.f()
}
```

Here, we know that I can *at least* assign the return value of `x.f` to a variable of type `A`. Even if `x` is an instance of `B`, which means that `f` returns a `B`, we can still assign that to a variable of type `A`.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper. I see your point. Return type and param type are different in that Swift compiler needs to know param type so that it can determine if the code in function body access or manipulate the param value in correct way. The return type actually matters also, but not to the funcion that returns it, but to the function that receives it (that is, the caller). That seems to be the reason why Swift compiler handles them differently.

Comment: BTW, your statement that `Self` shouldn't be used as param type is probably not correct. See an example in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self). I just submitted a question related to that discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66941225/how-is-self-in-protocol-interpreted-in-subclass). It would be much appreciated if you could take a look at that question also :)

Comment: @rayx Well, that discussion is about `Self` as a parameter of an _initialiser_, which doesn't have the "not useful" issue I talked about in my answer. I've edited the answer to specifically say "of methods". Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: On a second thought, why is it an issue that you can pass instance of A or its subclass to `g(x:)`? The code in the `g(x:)` func could deal with all of them as instances of A. This is a quite common approach in OOP. That said, I do find the [doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html) says that `Self` can only be used as a return type or in the body of a method. Anyway it seems mixing `Self` and subclass are full of pitfalls and should be avoided.

Comment: @rayx because that’s how subclasses work? The code in `g` cannot deal with all of them as having `A` as a parameter type  _precisely because_ of the semantics of `Self`.

Comment: The semantics of Self is quite confusing. See my another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66941225/how-is-self-in-protocol-interpreted-in-subclass).